# Multer + ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, multer, angular-file-upload

I'm trying to upload some files from AngularJS to my Node.js server and I always get req.file undefined.

This is my Angular upload (with [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload))

**CLIENT HTML**

```
<span ngf-select ngf-change="uploadFiles($files)" ngf-multiple="true">
    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
</span>
```

**CLIENT CONTROLLER**

```
    $scope.uploadFiles = function (files, error) {
      angular.forEach(files, function (file) {
        Upload.upload({
          url: '/api/upload',
          method: 'POST',
          data: {file: file}
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    });
  };
```

**SERVER ROUTE**

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest:'./files'}).any();
server.post('/api/upload', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);
    /* DISPLAY :
     { file: 
       { name: 'Migration_IP_COMMLINK.csv',
       data: <Buffer 52 41 44 52 45 50 4c 59 5f 49 44 3b 55 53 45 52 4e 41 4d 45 3b 43 55 52 52 45 4e 54 5f 49 50 3b 4e 45 57 5f 49 50 0d 0a 34 31 34 36 3b 30 33 38 38 34 ... >,
       encoding: '7bit',
       mimetype: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
       mv: [Function] } } */
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(req.files, req.file); // Display : [] undefined
    });
    res.status(200).json(null);
});
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Hey @Sparw, I'm not sure but I had a similar problem when I was working with multer. Try sending the files with multipart/form-data as the encoding.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you help, I have same result with multipart/form-data :(

Comment: And your files are defined in your controller?

Comment: yes, check my edit for the route

Comment: I solved my problem ! :) I was using another module "express-file-upload" which was in conflict with multer ...

Comment: Alright, good to know :D